# Ampscript isn't resolving

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-studio

So I have an Email template with a small HTML part which contains an AMPScript snippet that references a plain HTML block.

The problem I have is that **in the sent email AMPScript isn't resolved**. Am I doing something wrong?

Here below are the screenshots of the different components/config for further context.

---

***AMpscript snippet***

```
%%=ContentBlockbyID("61933")=%%
```

***Email template***

[image: Email template]

***Referenced block***

[image: Referenced block]

***Send configuration***

[image]

***Email received***

[image]

Comment: what type of content block are you using? Freeform, text or html?

Comment: @despicableme it's a plain HTML block :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like ContentBlockbyId does not work if the email is sent via send preview.

Please see below testing:

- Created a blank HTML content block.
- In email `%%=ContentBlockbyId("24736")=%%`
- When I did the test send I got the
  `%%=ContentBlockbyId("24736")=%%`
- However, when I did a live send to a data extension(only one
  record as my email address), I did got the content of

  %%=ContentBlockbyId("24736")=%%

You may want to try the live send. Also I noticed that you are using 
a capital D in %%=ContentBlockbyID("61933")=%%, you may need to use the lower case d.

Thanks